# How can I build a hash based in a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Example -

```
String1: "{t: 1},{t2: 2}"
String2: "{s: 1},{s2: 2}"
```

Build an array of hashes which returns

```
[ 
  {t: 1},
  {t2: 2},
  {s: 1},
  {s2: 2}
]
```

Comment: The result you expect is not a valid hash in ruby.

Comment: agreed, could be array of hashes like our friend below proactively assumed

Comment: Why the rush in selecting an answer? I and possibly others were still working on answers when you checkmarked a mere 30 minutes after posting the question, when there was only one answer.

Comment: You need to edit your question to exhibit valid Ruby objects. If you don't, it will surely invite downvotes and votes to close. You can see in my answer what I assumed those objects to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given an hash:

```
h = { String1: "{t: 1},{t2: 2}", String2: "{s: 1},{s2: 2}" }
```

and wish to return an array:

```
[ {t: 1}, {t2: 2}, {s: 1}, {s2: 2} ]
```

you can do it thus:

```
h.values.flat_map do |s|
  s.split(',').map do |t| 
    k,v = t.scan(/\w+/)
    { k.to_sym=>v }
  end
end
  #=> [{:t=>"1"}, {:t2=>"2"}, {:s=>"1"}, {:s2=>"2"}]
```

The steps:

```
a = h.values
  #=> ["{t: 1},{t2: 2}", "{s: 1},{s2: 2}"]
enum = a.flat_map
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["{t: 1},{t2: 2}", "{s: 1},{s2: 2}"]:flat_map>
```

The first element of the enumerator is passed to the block:

```
s = enum.next
  #=> "{t: 1},{t2: 2}"
c = s.split(',')
  #=> ["{t: 1}", "{t2: 2}"]
```

`map` maps each of `c`'s two elements to a hash:

```
k,v = "{t: 1}".scan(/\w+/)
  #=> ["t", "1"] 
{ k.to_sym=>v }
  #=> {:t=>"1"}
```

and

```
k,v = "{t2: 2}".scan(/\w+/)
  #=> ["t2", "2"] 
{ k.to_sym=>v }
  #=> {:t2=>"2"}
```

The second and final element of `enum` is now passed to the block:

```
s = enum.next
  #=> "{s: 1},{s2: 2}"
```

The above steps are repeated to obtain the two hashes `{:s=>1}` and `{:s2=>2}`. Since we are using [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), we obtain:

```
[{:t=>"1"}, {:t2=>"2"}, {:s=>"1"}, {:s2=>"2"}]
```

rather than:

```
[[{:t=>"1"}, {:t2=>"2"}], [{:s=>"1"}, {:s2=>"2"}]]
```

which is what we'd get if we used [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Comment: @Andrey, sorry, but I don't know Rails.

Answer (score 1):

What you are expecting is invalid, as @mudasobwa says.

But what you can do, is use [`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) to convert it to **array** of hashes:

```
a = "{t: 1},{t2: 2}"
#=> "{t: 1},{t2: 2}"
 b = "{s: 1},{s2: 2}"
#=> "{s: 1},{s2: 2}"
[a.split(','), b.split(',')].flatten.map{|a| eval a}
#=> [{:t=>1}, {:t2=>2}, {:s=>1}, {:s2=>2}]
```

Comment: although eval doesnt seem to handle well the convertion to hash when the string has multiple keys ex: a = "{t: 1, t2: 2}"

Comment: @user3087106 Why?  `eval "{t: 1, t2: 2}"  #=> {:t=>1, :t2=>2}
`

Comment: sorry the solution above does not handle multiple keys + multiple hashes... but I think you gave me what I needed, answer of how I can convert string to hash and a clue how I should merge them... thanks a lot man =)